# Printing above, not onto the bed

Tags: creality-ender-3

I just got an Ender 3 pro printer and set it up. I have levelled my bed and set the coordinates to (0, 0, 0) with the nozzle paper’s thickness away from the bed. When I started printing the default test dog, the machine moves to (0, 0, 5) which lifted the nozzle up and filament started oozing out without touching the bed. I also tried my own square design and the same happens. Is there anyway to not make it go up? I cannot make my bed go any higher.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please update your question to include some (e.g. 32 lines) of the lines of the G-code file of the dog. To be sure, also mention how you level the bed, you need to perform `G28` and move the head down to zero height and then level to paper thickness.

Comment: Sounds like your g-code is off.

Comment: It sounds like you changed the settings for the default z offset from the menu. See if you can reset it, or reset the machine to factory defaults.

Comment: Please add the information, else the community votes to close the question and the only way to get it reopened is through the reopen vote after a major update from you. We would love to help but this is a little too less information to work with.